# Error en ordenación de la una lista por punteros en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas estoy practicando ordenación y resulta que con este código, la lista no se ordena correctamente. Es un algoritmo de inserción, pero después de mucho debug no entiendo que es lo que está mal. Al desplazar a la izquierda el elemento que es menor, remplaza el elemento al que ha sustituido.

c++

```
void ordenarLista(tListaJugadores& lista) {
    int j;
    tJugador jugador;
    for (int i = 1; i < lista.cont; i++) {
        jugador = *lista.jugadores[i];
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (jugador.nombre < lista.jugadores[j - 1]->nombre)) {
            lista.jugadores[j] = lista.jugadores[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        *lista.jugadores[j] = jugador;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [so]. Aunque adivinamos que hace tu código, es mejor que intentes modificar tu pregunta e incluir un [mcve] para que podamos darte una respuesta certera. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((j > 0) && (jugador.nombre < lista.jugadores[j - 1]->nombre)) {
    lista.jugadores[j] = lista.jugadores[j - 1];
    j--;
}
```

En ese bucle sobreescribes la posición `[j]` con los datos del jugador que está en `[j-1]`. Con esto estás perdiendo información ya que  lo que había en la posición `[j]` se pierde para siempre.

Lo que tienes que hacer es intercambiar los datos de ambas posiciones:

```
while ((j > 0) && (jugador.nombre < lista.jugadores[j - 1]->nombre)) {
    std::swap(lista.jugadores[j], lista.jugadores[j - 1]);
    j--;
}
```

O bien:

```
while ((j > 0) && (jugador.nombre < lista.jugadores[j - 1]->nombre)) {
    tJugador temp = lista.jugadores[j];
    lista.jugadores[j] = lista.jugadores[j - 1];
    lista.jugadores[j-1] = temp;
    j--;
}
```